# How to allow someone else on another machine to access application deployed with docker

Tags: docker, flask, networking, web-deployment

I deployed an application using a third party image in a vm by just running:

`docker run -p 80:80 <the image>`

I can access the web app using an ip similar to this: 193.178.45.273/home.html

I'm able to hit that endpoint however, if a friend tries to access it on his computer, he's not able to. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Is your friend connected to the same network as you, or is he at a different house using a different router?

Comment: Different house different router

Answer (score 0):

Your question probably belongs on Unix & Linux StackExchange site, but in general terms, you probably need to do the following.

---

Find your external IP address - Google *"get own external IP address"*

---

Log into your router and set up:

- either a static or reserved IP address for the machine you are running docker on, so that it comes up with the same LAN local IP address every time it boots
- set up a *"Virtual Server"* a.k.a *"Port Forwarding"* to route all external requests for HTTP (port 80) to the static IP address of your docker machine

***Note that this completely exposes port 80 on your docker machine to the entire world!***

---

Now pass your external IP address to your friend and tell him to browse to:

```
http://EXTERNALIPADDRESS/home.html
```